# After setting password for utorrent on Ubuntu 17.04 at localhost:8080/gui I can't use it

Tags: 17.04, utorrent

I'm a newbie in Linux. I've installed utorrent and set up a password. Since then to reach localhost:8080/gui I need to enter a password, but after I enter it the "authentication is required" popup reappears over and over again and I can't use utorrent anymore.

[image: it keeps showing up]

Answer (score 5):

If this is the first time you are opening the web UI, enter `admin` as username and leave the password field empty.
After logging in to web UI, you can change the password by clicking on the gear icon and opening settings tab. In settings, click on Web UI on the left side and change the password then click on `Save settings` on top right. Now you can log in with your new username and password.

**In case of forgotten password:**
Close utserver using system monitor or by running `sudo killall utserver` in terminal.
Go to your utorrent folder and delete `settings.dat` file. Run utserver. Now you can log in to Web UI using default `admin` username and leaving password field empty.

Comment: But this is not my first time as I said before I'd set a password and after that I'm not able to login again and the authentication tab keeps opening again and again.

Comment: This means you are entering wrong username and password. You might had Caps Lock on or typed using another keyboard layout when setting new password.

Comment: Please check the new part added to my answer.

Comment: @AshishSiwal You are welcome. :) Please choose my answer as correct answer if you think it works. ;)

Comment: Thank you, Its working in system.